# How do i validate a text field for minimum characters?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I'm am trying to Validate my text fields to only submit with the right number of characters.  I tried the function below but it's being literal, only letting the number "10" submit and not characters less then or equal to it. How do i properly do it?

```
function validateForm(){
    var x=document.chip_insert
        txt=x.order_number.value;
    if (txt<=10) {
        return true
    }else{
        alert("Not a valid order number")
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: Use txt.length in your if

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah you get the length of a string easily by the .length() on a string.

But your String "x" is also an problem.
I think you cant just do "document.formxy"

Here a link with basics of getting DOM Elements in javascript
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_elements.asp

Comment: You were right as well, thank you for the link too, it helps a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the length of the string by doing txt.length which returns an int

Answer (score 0):

use `if (txt.length<=10) {` to get the length of the string. You are only comparing the value instead of the length.

Answer (score 0):

Try txt.length to count the number of characters

Answer (score 0):

You are not evaluating the **length** of the string but the string itself.
Instead of

```
if (txt <=10)
```

Try

```
if (txt.length <= 10)
```